# Unable to connect Vodafone Huawei dongle

Tags: wireless

I am using ubuntu 11.04 and I am trying to connect Vodafone Huawei dongle to access internate,But I am not getting any success to connect the net.Can someone tell me where I am doing the wrong part?Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Comment: did ubuntu detected the hardware and you have setup APN ?

Comment: nope..It didn't....

Comment: Edit your question with output of following command `lsusb -v` and device model.

Comment: The device model(dongle) is `Huawei K3570-Z` and when I used `lsusb -v` in terminal it showed a long list so which one should I paste here.

Comment: paste the output , (the long list) to http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and share the url here

Comment: Ok... the list is here  http://paste.ubuntu.com/933601/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this modem has problem in 11.04 as per google results. If the device LED is ok and it loaded as a cd drive,

Try the following,

Don't use memory card in the slot of modem if any.

1. open synaptic package manager and download these two libraries.

   - usb-modeswitch
   - usb-modeswitch-data
2. Press ALT+ F2 and type `gconf-editor`
3. Disable auto mount :
   Click on `apps` folder in left and then navigate to `nautilus`, double click on `preferences` directory.

   on right hand side panel,uncheck the following options:

   - media_automount
   - media_automount_open

   Check this option

   - media_autorun_never
4. Reboot system. You can keep usb stick connected.

Now that you have everything setup, you can create configuration for this USB modem in network connections.

Alternartively you can try with  [sakis3g](http://www.sakis3g.org/.) script. It is shell script specifically made for vodafone.

A detailed tutorial of both methods can be found here

http://skyfire.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Install-Vodafone-3G-USB-Modem-on-Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks @Web-E for your quick reply.I made successfully connect the device using your `first method`,but the problem is that when I am going to open any page with any browser then not a single page is opening.I checked the dongle in  another system with `Windows Xp ` and it is working good in that.So what is the wrong part in my system?

Comment: did you setup the APN?

Comment: yes I made it..but the pages are not opening..Please help me..