# Why is my Huawei E1550 dongle detected but unable to connect to the internet?

Tags: 12.04, usb-modem, huawei

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I am having problems getting my dongle to work. After I plug in  the modem the network notification shows me that the device has been detected, but each time I try to connect to the internet it displays an icon that shows its trying to connect and then instantly disconnects.

How can I get it to work?

Comment: Does any of these answers help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/73398/how-can-i-install-the-huawei-e1550-dongle

Comment: does ubuntu detect the modem and you can create a new mobile braodband connection ? Make sure to give correct APN, userID password (if require). After that if the same problem occurs  try this → http://askubuntu.com/questions/122537/unable-to-connect-vodafone-huawei-dongle-on-ubuntu-11-04/122742#122742

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue disabling the automount for such a device, editing my fstab with  "noauto,exec" options. This worked because these device are both a modem and removable media storage, and it seems one excludes the other.

Comment: Can you give more exact instructions?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my updated ubuntu (12.04 64-bit) after upgrade from 11.10 (modem worked without any hints).

To solve this problem, use terminal (linux or even windows - hyper terminal) to access AT commands and turn device to modem-only mode: AT^U2DIAG=0

In case you'll need other modes, you can turn it back:

AT^U2DIAG=0     (modem only)

AT^U2DIAG=1     (modem + CD-ROM)

AT^U2DIAG=255   (modem + CD-ROM + Card Reader)

AT^U2DIAG=256   (modem + Card Reader)

Answer (score 0):

just be sure to check your internet bill if you're billed by the Gb.     the Huwei decided it was a phone on some distros and the internet company decided I had put the chip in a phone charging an extra several hundred $.    since it was all data they did roll it back to keep me as a customer because I have no contract and own the Huwei internet key outright.